# linking config with react-navigation v5.9 for URL with query params

Tags: react-native, linker, react-navigation

I'm working with react-navigation and I'm trying to configure my linking element because I need it to use it in apps and web to. It works fine with simple URLs but I don't know how exactly include a URL with query params.
My URL is `/ecare/page?reference=XXX`

and here's my linking

```js
const linking = {
    prefixes: ['//my-prefix'],
    config: {
      screens: {
        Invoices: 'ecare/invoices',
        Products: {
          path: 'ecare/page/:reference',
        }
      }
    },
  }
```

How can I exactly parser my URL from my query param URL to my linking working fine?

Comment: Sorry, have you found any solution? I'm experiencing the same problem

Answer (score 1):

A late answer but it might help someone. I've also spent some time on this issue. Here's what I was missing.

Keys in the `screens` object correspond with the screen name.

So if you have the following screen:

```
<SomeScreen name={'invoices'} ... />
```

And you want to navigate to it with the following

```
const navigationProps = useLinkProps({
    to: {
      screen: 'invoices',
      params: { reference: someValue },
    },
  })
```

Then you have to specify your screen in the linking config as:

```
const linking = {
    prefixes: ['//my-prefix'],
    config: {
      screens: {
        ['invoices']: 'invoices/:reference'
      }
    },
  }
```

Not as `Invoices: 'invoices/:reference'`

So,

Key == Screen name

Path == any value you want

Answer (score -1):

You can take reference from ->
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/configuring-links/#passing-params